# Rails Direct Upload validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have Rails app where I am doing direct upload using Stimilus JS. I am trying to use same validation logic for JS and Rails server. Things are working fine for common content types such as `image, pdf, doc, powerpoint` etc. But when I upload `keynote` file to S3, JS is showing it's content types as `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey`, S3 bucket have same content type but Rails is giving me validation error because it is deteticing content type as `application/zip`. I can't add `application/zip` as content type due to security reasons.

But if I reload the blob then content type works fine eg `@user.document.blob.reload`. This will work fine for save action because I can do something like this

```
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 @user.document.blob.reload
 @user.save!
```

But I won't be able to reload for update action because it will reload the previously uploaded document. Below code wont work

```
@user.document.blob.reload
@user.update(user_params)
```

However I can do something like this for update, but it looks dirty. There must be better way to do this.

```
@user.assign_attributes(user_params)
@user.document.blob.reload
@user.save
```

So how to solve this problem where Rails is detective content type as `application/zip` for files like `keynotes` ? I also tried to define new `MIMI type` in rails app like this

```
Mime::Type.register "application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey", :key
```

But Rails have different MIMI type of keynote files, however JS is using this MIMI type for Keynote files. This is only one example but I need to handle same logic for `pages` and linux file format as well.

I am using `active storage validations gem` if that makes any difference. In Rails i have validation like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  CONTENT_TYPE = %w[
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
    application/vnd.apple.keynote
    application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey
   ].freeze

  validates :document, content_type: CONTENT_TYPE,
                   size: { less_than: 10.megabytes, message: 'size cannot be larger 
                           than 10 MB.' }
```

And I am passing same `CONTENT_TYPE` in JS to validate as well. There must be better way to do validation on JS as well as validation on Rails server side for Direct Uploads.

**UPDATE:**

Same problem remains even when doing server side file upload. Content type in params is different to what Rails is detecting content type for `pages, keynotes`. It's always `application/zip`

Comment: Not sure where "application/zip" is coming from. I am assuming this has an extension of ".key". Both `active_storage` and `active_storage_validations` uses `marcel` for MIME types and `Marcel::MimeType.for extension: '.key'` returns `"application/vnd.apple.keynote"`. Can you provide any additional context?

Comment: @engineersmnky, Yes I already looked in Marcel table to see the content type of key. But when browser upload `.key file` or `.pages file`, it's not setup as `application/vdn.apple.keynote`,it been setup as `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey` in chrome and something else in different browsers. Even if i put byebug and see params value as `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey` for content_type, asking Rails content type for file is returning as `application/key`. No issue with common file types such as doc, docx, ppt, ppt, png, jpg, jpeg. only issue with Mac file formats.

Comment: What do you mean asking rails for the content_type? Can you show where it returns `application/zip` or `application/key`. It is difficult to help without actual debugging details

Comment: @engineersmnky in create action in controller `@user = User.new(user_params); @user.document.content_type` is returning `application/key` `User has_one_attached :document`